# User Defined Data Types in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, user-defined-types

I am migrating a MSSQL database to MySQL and having some issue while creating a table with user defined data types. I have researched a bit on this and it seems that there is no way to have custom data types in MySQL. So, for below MSSQL statement, what is the best alternative statement in MySQL

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdvisorOutput](
[SeqNo] [int] NOT NULL,
[RowKey] [tinyint] NULL,
[RowSubKey] [varchar](4) NULL,
[RuleResult] [dbo].[AdvisorOutputRuleResult] NULL)
```

The above statement has 'AdvisorOutputRuleResult' as user defined data type.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Curious, is there a way to see the details of the user defined data type? (I've never used MSSQL).

Comment: MySQL does not support user defined data types (any many other modern SQL features)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see. So, whats the workaround or suggested approach?

Comment: Personally I'd ditch MySQL in favour of Postgres (which supports custom data types - with even more features than SQL Server) - but I guess that is not an option for you.

Comment: there is a JSON type